# Issues while using Stylecop addin for Monodevelop

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop, stylecop

I am trying to use the Stylecop addin for Monodevelop - http://addins.monodevelop.com/Project/Index/54. I have a custom policy file that i use in Visual studio (its a Settings.Stylecop file), and now i want to use the same in Monodevelop (Xamarin Studio). I put the Settings.Stylecop file in the solution directory, but Stylecop does not really seem to use the policies from that file.
Has anyone used the stylecop addin with Monodevelop (Xamarin Studio)? Where does Stylecop read the policies from in this case?
Thanks much!

Comment: I have the same problem. I need it to exclude a couple of the rules... Have you figured it out yet?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i was just able to get it working by restarting Xamarin Studio, and then putting the Settings.Stylecop file back to solution. It picks up my rules now.